# Unset click listeners inside adapter to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Current situation:

[image]

As you can see, click listener is getting leaked. Why is that? I know one solution, where in adapter I can set `clickListener` as `WeakReference`, but this means, that I have to do this everywhere, which seems wrong. I want to know the exact root of problem...

I create adapter like this:

`mAdapter = new XAdapter(.., .., .., this);` where `this` is implemented class in fragment.

In adapter I set listener like this:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    if (position != NO_POSITION) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(position)
    }
}
```

Why is this happening and how to avoid this?

Comment: Override `RecyclerView.Adapter` callbacks `onViewAttachedToWindow(VH holder)` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH holder)` to set and unset the listeners. They are not memory leaks if they are true weak references, when a GC occurs they will be reclaimed.

Comment: How would I do that for all elements that I've set listener? Also... This really does not answer WHY this should be done and what is causing this? :(

Comment: `How would I do that for all elements that I've set listener` - a view holder is a shared/recycled view, you only need click listeners for the amount of view holders you have that are visible on screen. PS I made a comment, that would solve your problem, not an answer that explains the problem .. otherwise I would have posted an answer. Before checking the hprof file you should really do a forced GC, then a memory dump.

Comment: @MarkKeen I see.. Well, this didn't help either way. Still showing as references. I did forced GC as well. :)